# Display messages from both users ORDER By time

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

my problem is that I want to display the messages between two users and order them by time.
I nmanaged to display the messages from each user but it displays first for the user George and the for user Niklakis as it shows in the image below...
[image]

What I want is to display both of the messages order by time.
This is part of my code...

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recip='$view' ORDER BY time DESC";
        $query2  = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recip='$username' ORDER BY time DESC";
        $result = queryMysql($query);
        $result2 = queryMysql($query2);
        $num    = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $num2    = mysql_num_rows($result2);

        for ($j = 0 ; $j < $num ; ++$j)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            if ($row[3] == 0 || $row[1] == $username || $row[2] == $username)
            {
                echo date('M jS \'y g:ia:', $row[4]);
                echo " <a href='messages.php?view=$row[1]'>$row[1]</a> ";

                if ($row[3] == 0)
                    echo "wrote: &quot;$row[5]&quot; ";
                else echo "private message: <span class='whisper'>" .
                      "&quot;$row[5]&quot;</span> ";

                if ($row[2] == $username)
                    echo "[<a href='messages.php?view=$view" ."&erase=$row[0]'>erase</a>]";

                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < $num2 ; ++$j)
        {
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);

            if ($row2[3] == 0 || $row2[1] == $username || $row2[2] == $username)
            {
                echo date('M jS \'y g:ia:', $row2[4]);
                echo " <a href='messages.php?view=$row2[1]'>$row2[1]</a> ";

                if ($row2[3] == 0)
                    echo "wrote: &quot;$row2[5]&quot; ";
                else echo "private message: <span class='whisper'>" .
                      "&quot;$row2[5]&quot;</span> ";

                if ($row2[2] == $username)
                    echo "[<a href='messages.php?view=$view" ."&erase=$row2[0]'>erase</a>]";

                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
```

I can understand that my problem happens because I have two different **for loops** and I probably need only ***ONE* for loop** to do this work. But I tried and I could find a way to do this.
Can you help?
Thank you.

Comment: is `$view = $username` ?

Comment: @MySQLRockstar no it is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same code for both query results (tip for the future: PHP supports something like functions :D try it out) and your queries have the same structure so why don't you just fecht all entries for both users and sort them? Have you tried this out?

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (recip='$username' AND auth='$view') OR (recip='$view' AND auth='$username') ORDER BY time DESC";
```

Comment: LOL i knew that it was an easy mistake :P ... Thank you